# How can I set the default Scope in IntelliJ 12 for Find Usages?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

I've returned to IntelliJ after a long hiatus for Android development so I'm getting used to it again. The problem I have is that for example when you want to see where is a class being used, you'd position the caret in the class declaration and issue <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> (on Mac OS X) to *Find Usages*, which is returning stuff from mapping.txt and seeds.txt as well as the .java results, and even tho I can set up the *defaults* by doing <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> and un-tick the: *search for text occurrences* and even change the *scope* from Project Files to a custom scope (for example), these options ***are not saved*** when I invoke *Find Usages* again.

Does anybody know of a way to personalize the *Find Usages* so it's more close to what Eclipse would do? (I.e., find the real usages instead of a text search for occurrences).

Comment: There is a related issue logged at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87037, check the comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reporting back from the future: the behaviour described in the question has now been implemented ([Intellij issue mentioned in the comments](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87037)).

To configure <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to run in a default scope, start by running it against some Symbol

[image: Usages found]

Clicking on the wrench icon, one can select one of the pre-defined scopes, or create a new one (using the <kbd>...</kbd> button).

[image: List of scopes]

The <kbd>+</kbd> creates a new scope. Find the folder in which to look, and click <kbd>Include recursively</kbd>. And voila!

[image: Create a scope]

Any consequent searches will use that scope until it is changed.

Comment: I saw that, nice. It only took them 3+ years and over 200 emails in threads in the forums. :)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>, use the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>. This will open a pop-up for you to make a selection about Scope, Test occurrences, and types of usage. You will have to make this selection one time. The next time you press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> then your choices are remembered.

The result is that <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> followed by <kbd>enter</kbd> gives you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was already aware of that shortcut, but it's nowhere near the same as cmd+alt. You get a floating (or pinned/docked) window which you have to later dismiss with shift-enter… it covers part of the screen, etc.